# shell script on linux

Tags: linux, shell, cron

here is my shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

crawlers(){
    nohup scrapy crawl a &
    nohup scrapy crawl b &
    wait $!
    nohup scrapy crawl f &
    nohup scrapy crawl g &
    wait $!
    nohup scrapy crawl h &
    nohup scrapy crawl i &
    wait $!
    nohup scrapy crawl i &
    nohup scrapy crawl j &
    nohup scrapy crawl k &
    wait $!
    nohup scrapy crawl l &
    nohup scrapy crawl m &
}

PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export PATH

python add_columns.py &
wait $!
crawlers &
wait $!
python final_script.py &
```

what i want to RUN **first** add_columns.py script

then **crawlers** script (**all scripts in crawlers are asynchronous** )

finally want to run **final_script.py**

but using above shell script

final_script.py is executing before ending

```
nohup scrapy crawl l &
nohup scrapy crawl m &
```

although i put wait on cralwers

```
crawlers &
wait $!
```

LASTLY how can i achive to call final_script.py only after completion of all jobs in crawlers() method.

thanks

Comment: remove "&" from all calls apart from "scrapy crawl", remove all calls to "wait", add "for pid in $(jobs -p); do wait $pid || exit $?; done" to the end of the function "crawlers"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, why bother backgrounding things that you immediately `wait` for?

Second, within the `crawlers` function, you're only `wait`ing on half the calls; the other half could still be running.

Use `wait` without arguments to wait for all currently active children to exit. This would be a better version:

```
#!/bin/bash

crawlers(){
    nohup scrapy crawl a &
    nohup scrapy crawl b &
    nohup scrapy crawl f &
    nohup scrapy crawl g &
    nohup scrapy crawl h &
    nohup scrapy crawl i &
    nohup scrapy crawl i &
    nohup scrapy crawl j &
    nohup scrapy crawl k &
    nohup scrapy crawl l &
    nohup scrapy crawl m &

    wait
}

PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export PATH

python add_columns.py

crawlers

python final_script.py
```

Comment: thanks for your contribution i crawler function i need to wait half processes to end before next get started , yes i need to add wait at the end of crawler as well.

but why its only working in crawler function ? is waiting after the crawlers call should not wait to end all child process ending with in the crawlers ?